# React JS Infinite slider issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build an infinite slider.

When I scroll through the slider the last cloned item shows as expected but the slider stops. I want to continue scrolling through infinitely, this slider should always have another item to scroll to.

Here is my "rails" array within my constructor which are imported components:

```
import MusicRail from '../../components/MusicRail';
import GamesRail from '../../components/GamesRail';
import MoviesRail from '../../components/MoviesRail';

constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
      indexX: 0,
      indexY: 1
   }

   this.rails = [
      MusicRail,
     GamesRail,
     MoviesRail
  ]
}
```

I'm then updating the rail after cloning the first and last items to append to the first and last positions of the array.

```
let rails = this.rails;
let firstObject = this.rails[0];
let lastObject = this.rails.slice(-1)[0];
this.rails = [lastObject, ...rails, firstObject];
```

Here is my onMoveVertical function - the direction is bound to another function setupKeys which is below:

```
onMoveVertical(direction) {
    if(!this.state.active || this.state.profileMenu.active) return;

    const moveLocal = (direction) => {
      let {indexY} = this.state;
      indexY = (direction === 'UP') ? (indexY === 0) ? 0 : indexY - 1 : (indexY < this.rails.length-1 ) ? indexY + 1 : this.rails.length-1;

      this.setState({
        indexY,
      });
    };

    const activeComponent = this[`${this.className}-${this.state.indexY}`];
    if(activeComponent && activeComponent.onMoveVertical) {
      const canMove = activeComponent.onMoveVertical(direction);

      if(!canMove) {
        moveLocal(direction);
      }
    } else {
      moveLocal(direction);
    }

  }
```

setupKeys function:

```
setupKeys() {
    key('up', this.keyScope, this.onMoveVertical.bind(this, 'UP'));
    key('down', this.keyScope, this.onMoveVertical.bind(this, 'DOWN'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving this.rails into state. When the property is just on this/the object, updating it's value won't cause render to be called, so the view won't update.

Comment: Thank you, I updated state with your suggestion though this didn't work.

Comment: Maybe is there an issue with the way I am setting state?

Comment: Hmm, using `this.setState({rails: [lastObject, ...rails, firstObject]})`?It might be somewhere else, but I can't see the render function or the function that triggers the update to rails to follow it.

Comment: Also I assume the constructor looks similar to this  -
    `constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    
       this.state = {
          indexX: 0,
          indexY: 1,
          rails: [ MusicRail, GamesRail, MoviesRail]
       }
    }`

Comment: Yes this is how state looks, I will update the initial post with the full code. I think the best place to update state will be in the onMoveVertical function?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking `onMoveVertical` would be the best spot for that. Also, it looks like `setUIElements` needs to be called at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180355/discussion-between-filth-and-r-wright).